# How do we show that narrow convergence is only needed on a spanning uniformly dense subset

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, gradient-flows

At the beginning of Chapter 5 of Ambrosio's Gradient Flows book, he introduces the idea of a narrowly convergent sequence of measures as...

"A sequence $(\mu_n) \subset \mathcal{P}(x)$ is narrowly convergent to $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(x)$ as $n\to\infty$ if

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}f(x)d\mu_n(x) = \int_X f(x)d\mu(x) $$
for every function $f \in C_b^0(X)$.

Ambrosio then claims that it is sufficient to check this on a subset of $C_b^0(X)$ such that $span(\mathcal(F))$ is a uniformly dense subset of $C_0^b(X)$. I have attempted a proof, but I honestly dont know if it is correct, or how I would be intended to show it in the first place. The attempt follows.Suppose there exists $\mathcal{F}\subset C_0^b(X)$ such that $span(\mathcal{F})$ is uniformly dense in $C_0^b(X)$. Let $g \in span(\mathcal{F})$. Then

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int g\mu_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_ig_i d\mu_n$$
However, as each $g_i \in \mathcal{F}$ and we have narrow convergence on $\mathcal{F}$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_ig_i d\mu_n = \int \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_ig_i d\mu = \int g d\mu$$.

We have now shown the claim holds on $span(F)$ itself. Now let $f \in C_0^b(X)$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and by uniform density we see that there must exist $g \in span(\mathcal(F))$ for which.

$$ \| f - g\|_{\infty} < \varepsilon$$

Therefore, $$|\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f-g d\mu_n| < \varepsilon$$. Splitting the integral we see that $$ | \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f d\mu_n - \int g d\mu | < \varepsilon.$$
Because the choice of $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we can show that
$$ |\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f d\mu_n - \int f d\mu| < \varepsilon $$
and therefore
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu.$$

I feel most like I have handwaved the later half. My largest concern is the span definition -- surely with an infinite set the number of coefficients I would need could blow up -- and the sum inside the integral could be infinite, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything with the span is fine. Only ordinary finite linear combinations occur in the span, and the integral is linear. For the latter half, note that

$$\bigg|\int f~\mathrm d\mu-\int f~\mathrm d\mu_n\bigg|=\bigg|\int f~\mathrm d\mu-\int g~\mathrm d\mu+\int g~\mathrm d\mu-\int g~\mathrm d\mu_n+\int g~\mathrm d\mu_n-\int f~\mathrm d\mu_n\bigg|$$
$$\leq \bigg|\int f~\mathrm d\mu-\int g~\mathrm d\mu\bigg|+\bigg|\int g~\mathrm d\mu-\int g~\mathrm d\mu_n\bigg|+\bigg|\int g~\mathrm d\mu_n-\int f~\mathrm d\mu_n\bigg|$$
$$\leq \int |f-g|~\mathrm d\mu+\bigg|\int g~\mathrm d\mu-\int g~\mathrm d\mu_n\bigg|+\int |g-f|~\mathrm d\mu_n$$
$$\leq\epsilon+\bigg|\int g~\mathrm d\mu-\int g~\mathrm d\mu_n\bigg|+\epsilon.$$
By narrow convergence, the last part is at most $3\epsilon$ for $n$ large enough.